# why this codes didn't run from python?

Tags: python

what is the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Iran2\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11908\4282535460.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySpice'
```

despite I installed it and when i do it in anaconda PowerShell prompt it say Successfully installed PySpice-1.5

Comment: format your code to make it readable. Post your conda install command and the result (where did it get installed). Open a python-shell and print sys.executable. I suspect you installed into a wrong interpreter.

Comment: Also, you need a better question title.

Comment: Are you certain you activated the anaconda environment, that you installed the package on, on the shell you are running from?

Answer (score 0):

Python version management and installation management can be a pain. It's hard to know without more information about your setup, but I imagine you have multiple python versions installed. Possibly Anaconda and another installation that is being used to run the code.

Each python installation handles it's own modules and packages. Assuming you are running the scrip like this `python myScript.py`, you can check the packages on that installation of python via `python -m pip list`. If you don't see PySpice, try `python -m pip install PySpice`.